# Script to delete files older than 2 days and log file name to a file with creation time and deletion time

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to delete files older than 2 days and write the deleted file names to a log file along with creation/modified time and deletion time.

Eg:
filename creationTime deletetionTime

> test1 11-08-2020T08:38:16+05:30 12-08-2020T10:18:42+05:30
> test2 11-08-2020T08:38:16+05:30 12-08-2020T10:18:42+05:30

I have script to delete files older than 2 days and log the filename to file but not getting how to print along with creation/modified date and deletion time.

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/test"
filename=*.txt
logfile=/tmp/$(date +%d-%m-%Y).log
days=-60

find $path -mmin $days -name "*.wav" -type f -print0 -delete | xargs -0 basename -a >> $logfile
```

Can someone help me to achieve that above output?

Comment: The `$filename` variable is not used.

Comment: yeah sorry, I hardcoded the name with *.wav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have deleted a file, there is no longer a possibility to `stat` it for `atime`/`mtime` information.

As well, the `-printf` action in GNU `find` has a `%f` specifier for printing the file's basename, so there's really no need for the external `xargs` / `basename` combo.

So you could get the basename and modification time in a `-printf` like

```
find "$path" -type f -name "*.wav" -mmin "$days" -printf '%f\t%T+\n'
```

You could then execute a `date` command just before (or just after) the `-delete` to get the deletion time:

```
find "$path" -type f -name "*.wav" -mmin "$days" -printf '%f\t%T+\t' -exec date '+%F+%H:%M:%S.%N' \; # -delete
```

(remove the `#` to proceed with the deletions only once you are happy that it is doing what you want).

For other date/time format options see the relevant man pages - I chose `%T+` for the GNU long form modification time in `find`, then chose date format `+%F+%H:%M:%S.%N` to mimic that.